# Can not stop access point

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi-pico, access-point

I'm using CicuitPython V8.1 on a Raspberry Pi Pico W. I import wifi.radio and use `radio.start_ap()` to start an access point, but from `radio.stop_ap()` I get:

> NotImplementedError: Stopping AP is not supported.

I can reset with `microprocessor.reset()` but that's kind of drastic. How do I stop the access point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same frustration but came back to it with a clear head this morning.
This worked for me, but I've only just done it once.

1. Ensure nothing is connected to the AP (your phone etc.)
2. Restart the board

The board should now be in Station Mode by default.